# Facebook Jobs Tab Integration

Tags: facebook, integration

I know next to nothing about coding (though I wish I did) but I reached out to Facebook via chat, they didn't know they answer so they sent me to a Facebook Developers Facebook page I had to join. They wouldn't let me join and their description sent me here SO here I am. 
Our company is part of a larger organization and our jobs sometimes get buried in their jobs site. We want to do something similar to that of IHC: https://www.facebook.com/Intermountain/app/124100234306620/
They have what looks like to be an Indeed integration for their jobs/careers tab. Facebook says they don't support integration... so how can IHC have this? Does anybody know? Can I make this happen?

Comment: That is a Page Tab App. You can read about the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

Comment: They are showing content from indeed.com in a frame, there are errors in the console `Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://fbcompany3.indeed.com".`